# Robot Framework With Appium - Windows Devices

Tags: windows, uwp, appium, robotframework

I was researching if we could write tests In Robot Framework with Appium to UI-Automate tests on a **windows device (Tablet)**, I have tests set up for android testing in Robot Framework that use AppiumLibrary this all works fine.

I have seen That i Could use `uiautomator.exe` but I prefer to use Robot Framework and  appium for multiple devices (if its supported).

Is this possible? if not what would be the best solution for me?

Comment: You should have shown more effort in experimenting Appium on multiple devices, and then be specific on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to test multiple devices with AppiumLibrary. You need to have connectors to Appium server on different ports. Here is a nice 7 minutes video demonstrating with real devices: [Multi Device Tests on Android using the Robot Framework (by Solution57)](https://youtu.be/lZvpRdyX38M)